# Plot scale gradient with a discrete cutoff in geom_tile()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi guys I have a sample data frame as such:

```
df = data.frame(sender = "Bob",
                receiver = c("Amy","James","Ronald","Andy","Harry","Mary"),
                frequency = c(0,1,2,3,5,10))
```

I want to plot it with `geom_tile` in this format:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=sender,y=receiver,fill=frequency)) + 
  geom_tile(stat = "identity",position = "identity",colour = "black") +  
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white","red"))
```

Currently I'm using the `scale_fill_gradientn` to create the white to red gradient but is it possible to incorporate a cutoff where if the value was 0 it would be white and anything larger than 0 (aka starting from 1) it would already be red and then still keep having an increasing gradient as the frequency increases? I tried putting more colours into the `colours` argument but it cannot specify where the cutoff starts for the data, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `values` to assign the colours to values (on a normalized scale between 0 and 1)

```r
ggplot(df, aes(sender, receiver, fill = frequency)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = "black") +  
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("white", "#FFA0A0", "red"),
                       values  = c(0, 0.001, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Can I confirm that the ```values``` argument are automatically normalized (so I can only type numbers within the range of 0 to 1 and anything larger than 1 wouldn't work)?

Comment: That's right @Jeff, so in your case you just need your first non-white color to be an arbitrarily low non-zero number.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `scale_fill_gradient` instead of `scale_fill_gradientn`. You specify your color for `low` values and `high` values and set `limits` from lowest to highest where you want the color step scheme to be applied. Assign a color for `na.value`, e.g. not within the set range for the color step scheme.

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=sender,y=receiver,fill=frequency)) + 
  geom_tile(stat = "identity",position = "identity",colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "indianred2", high = "red",
                      limits = c(1, max(df$frequency)), na.value = "white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I `reorder` the y-axis so that you get a increasing gradient of red using the `scale_fill_gradient` function. You can use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(sender = "Bob",
                receiver = c("Amy","James","Ronald","Andy","Harry","Mary"),
                frequency = c(0,1,2,3,5,10))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=sender,y=reorder(receiver, frequency),fill=frequency)) + 
  geom_tile(stat = "identity",position = "identity",colour = "black") +  
  ylab("receiver") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "indianred2", high = "red", limits = c(1, 10), na.value = "white")
```

Output:

[image]